# i want to type student name in the text field and show his grade in the label (swift 4)

Tags: swift, dictionary, label, textfield

i want to type student name in the text field and show his grade in the label
i have a Dictionary withe student name and his grade and i want to put the student name in the text field and press the button and then his grade appears in the label and everytime i put a student name i want his grade appears

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let studentsNamesAndGrades = ["Bushra":92,"Reem":80,"Maha":100,"Leen":74,"Sara":85]

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel2: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func myButton2(_ sender: Any) {

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}    
}
```

---

sorry i'm new in xcode, when i put ur codes i got an error message

**Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Int]' with an index of type 'String?'**

it appeared after this code

```
 let studentGrade = studentsNamesAndGrades[nameFromField]
```

Comment: Haven't you researched or tried anything? Like how to get the value from a text field or how to set the value for a label?

Comment: I tried but I couldn't find the solution :(

Comment: To get you started [UILabel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel), [UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield), [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary).

Comment: Your 'question' reads more like a request where you are asking for someone to just give you the code that does what you described.  You would have better success if you did as much on your own and asked a more direct question.

Comment: sorry my english its not that good and i'm new in Xcode so i don't know how to asked a more direct question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work you need to make your action take text input from the field, and use it as `key` to the Dictionary. In case there's a name that matches text from the field, the `value` of that key will be placed in label.

```
@IBAction func myButton2(_ sender: Any) {
  myLabel2.text = "\(studentsNamesAndGrades[myTextField.text])"
}
```

Same code in details:

```
@IBAction func myButton2(_ sender: Any) {
  let nameFromField = myTextField.text 
  let studentGrade = studentsNamesAndGrades[nameFromField] // this will produce optional Int
  if let studentGrade = studentGrade { // this will unwrap optional
    myLabel2.text = "\(studentGrade)" // this will interpolate Int value as String and assign to the labelText
  } else { // if unwrapping failed meaning there's no value for this key
    myLabel2.text = "No grade for this student found"
  }

}
```

Comment: Using an `if let` to both get and unwrap a value is pretty standard swift so I would suggest you merge row 2 and 3.

Comment: Of course, as you know it could be all achieved in one line, the point was to show the logic with the step-by-step solution.

Comment: myTextField.text, this returns an optional.

Comment: thank u sooo much it works when i add ! in the end of nameFromField in the third line. like this >> let studentGrade = studentsNamesAndGrades[nameFromField!]